# Combining discrete and continuous variables

Tags: density-function, cumulative-distribution-function

I need to find the pdf of a random variable which is a mixture of discrete and continuous random variables. I have seen on this website but it does not exist in the general case, but maybe in this one it does.

In any case, I have $X \sim Bern(p)$ where $p$ is known, and I have $Y = XW+(1-X)Z$ where $W,Z$ are both continuous with pdf also known. For the moment, I've tried to 
\begin{align*}
\text{cdf}_Y (y) & = P( Y \leq y) = P( XW+(1-X)Z \leq y) \\
& = P( ... \leq y \mid X=0 ) + P( ... \leq y \mid X =1) \\
& = \text{cdf}_W(y) + \text{cdf}_Z(y)
\end{align*}
I am just not sure I am allowed to go from the first line to the second...is this correct ? Does anyone have any suggestion on this problem ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Is this for some subject? Note that your first, second, and third lines are *all* wrong in some way. The first line is missing a $Z$, the second is missing a term out in front of each $P$ and the third is plainly wrong without even trying to think about the problem, since the sum of two cdfs can't itself be a cdf.

Comment: There's some information here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_density#Finite_and_countable_mixtures

Comment: Thanks Glen for the constructive comment. This actually isn't homework. As for the mistakes above, I apologise for those due to not proofreading myself (ligns 1 and 2) and the third one is just my ignorance.

Comment: The third line you should be able to reject from knowing nothing more than: cdfs are monotonic nondecreasing, and must approach 0 at the left and 1 at the right. (From which you should see that eventually the sum of two cdfs with the same argument must exceed 1 and so cannot be a cdf.) If not for some subject, how did such a question arise?

Comment: I do not understand why you are being aggressive here. 1) If I did not have anything to learn I would not post here, 2) it can be "for some subject " without being homework (ie not being assigned/marked/looked at by anyone). I do understand now that the third line is easily seen to be wrong, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: I do not understand why you think I am being aggressive at any point. (1) I was attempting to give you more information about how you could figure more things out. That is, I was trying to help you to learn. Your final sentence shows that I actually did that. Please keep in mind there's a word-limit, so comments will necessarily be very terse -- and with this extra sentence, this comment has just gone over that limit, so... (ctd)

Comment: (ctd) ... (2) My question about how it arises was [asked for a reason](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) - the `self-study` tag applies for standard bookwork like this even when it's not 'homework', even when it's not assigned, even when it's not looked at by anyone else. (Indeed, even when it's not directly associated with any subject, but that's a relatively rare situation.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P( Y \leq y) $

$= P( Y \leq y|X=1)P(X=1) + P( Y \leq y|X=0)P(X=0)$

$=P( Y \leq y|X=1)p + P( Y \leq y|X=0)(1-p)$

$=pP( W\leq y) + (1-p)P( Z \leq y)$

So $F_Y(y)=pF_W(y)+(1-p)F_Z(y)$ and thus $f_Y(y)=pf_W(y)+(1-p)f_Z(y)$